# creating view and procedure for non existense table?

Tags: sql-server

I have one query regards the creating a procedure and view.

Simple :

```
Create Procedure usp_demoXYZ
As
Begin
Select * from Table1 -- This table is not present in current Database
End
```

After execute the above query, query is executed successfully and created procedure.

But same things we apply in time of creating View.

```
Create View Vw_demoXYZ
As
Select * from Table1 -- This table is not present in current Database
```

after that I m running above query , sql server is showing error..

```
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Vw_demoXYZ, Line 4

Invalid object name 'Table1'
```

Answer (score 1):

Stored procedures use Deferred Name Resolution while views does not do that. Deferred Name Resolution means when you create a stored proc it only checks if syntax of the statements are correct and not if the objects/tables  it is referring to are there in database. That only occurs at runtime when you execute stored proc.

More details can be found here :

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190686(v=sql.105).aspx